# Simple arithmetic in PHP

Tags: php

Here is a simple php program which gives a strange output. Can anyone explain why it is coming like this and how to get the expected output?

```
<?php
$a=2;$b=3;

echo "<br> ADD:".$a+$b;
echo "<br> SUB:".$a-$b;
echo "<br> MUL:".$a*$b;
echo "<br> DIV:".$a/$b;
?>
```

Output:

```
3-3
MUL:6
DIV:0.66666666666667
```

Expected Output:

```
ADD:5
SUB:-1
MUL:6
DIV:0.66666666666667
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is because the string concatenation operator `.` has the [same precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) as the add/sub operators, and all of them are left-associative. This means that evaluation proceeds left-to-right, so `"<br> ADD:".$a` is evaluated first and the result is added to `3`. This particular string converts to zero and 0 + 3 = 3. Similar for the subtraction.

Solution: put the arithmetic in parentheses.

```
echo "<br> ADD:".($a+$b);
echo "<br> SUB:".($a-$b);
```

On the other hand, mul/div have higher precedence than concatenation so they produce the expected result.